# Android Jetpack: lifecycle-aware recurrent periodic task execution with LiveData and ViewModels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager, kotlin-coroutines

My app already uses some recent Android patterns for network calls:

- `LiveData` class
- MVVM architecture with `ViewModel` class
- Kotlin coroutines for Repository classes
- `Retrofit` interface etc.

Now I want to implement common feature which is automatic fetching current data from API **every few minutes**.

I read about `WorkManager` and give it a shot - I implemented it but I then saw that `WorkManager` (`JobScheduler`) keeps running after closing app which is not what I want. I also felt like `WorkManager` API is too much overkill for that simple task.

Then I read a [guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks) on Codepath that suggests `Handler` class for main thread repetitive jobs and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for background repetitive tasks. I know that they will probably work fine but I'm not sure if they are best solution.

My question is: what's currently the best way for recurrent API calls that:

- works with `LiveData` and `ViewModel` classes (observable result like normal API call)
- is Kotlin-friendly (any way to make coroutine recurrent?)
- is "lifecycle-aware", meaning that it will stop when app goes to the background?

Comment: I have a similar situation. Did you find any best practice? which scenario did you use at last?

Comment: @Evil I managed to use `Handler` class with some inline function - see my code [here](https://github.com/krzdabrowski/android-kotlin-air-purrr/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/krzdabrowski/airpurrr/main/current/DataCurrentFragment.kt), `runPeriodicFetching()`. I guess it's not the cleanest and best practice but couldn't make it better without big boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager is for guaranteed works that needs to be executed even if your app exit or the device is restarted. From your description this doesn't seem your use case.

A threadpool seems the best option in this case, but you can judge yourself starting from this guide: "[Background Tasks](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background)".

Comment: By threadpool you mean ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor? I've come across a flowchart in "Choosing the right solution for your work" in your link and it suggests WorkManager, hence my question on SO..

Comment: Yeah, sorry, probably not the best reference for your case. I think that the main confusion here is about "background processing" intended to run when your app is in the background, and "off the main thread" processing. Intended for operations that needs to happen off the main thread. WorkManager is one of the solution for the first case: your app maybe in the background and  WorkManager runs your Work. If you need to run something while your app is in the foreground WorkManager is probably overkill. Here another guide for threadpools https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads.